# pattern in C# don't know how to create

Tags: c#

I need help creating this certain shape on C#

Link to image of shape: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-5xzVHPm8xG4wvkcGgtZ4IBx2uSgwS4u/view?usp=sharing

I have tried making this shape for a long while but can't seem to make it properly the code I currently have just prints the same first pattern twice back to back.

```
 using System;
 namespace Patterns   
 {  
 class Program  
 {  
 static void Main(string[] args)  
 {  
   int i, j, k;  
   for (i = 1; i <= 5; i++)  
   {  
     for (j = 1; j <= 6 - i; j++)  
     {  
       Console.Write("*");  
     }  
     for (k = 1; k < i; k++)  
     {  
       Console.Write(" ");  
     }  
     for (j = 1; j <= 6 - i; j++)  
     {  
       Console.Write("*");  
     }  
     Console.Write("\n");  
   }  
   for (i = 2; i <= 5; i++)  
   {  
     for (j = 1; j <= i; j++)  
     {  
       Console.Write("*");  
     }  
     for (k = 1; k <= 5 - i; k++)  
     {  
       Console.Write(" ");  
     }  
     for (j = 1; j <= i; j++)  
     {  
       Console.Write("*");  
     }  
     Console.WriteLine();  
   }      
 }  
 }  
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Whoa, that's a big block of unreadable code :) I think we need to simplify a bit:

```
int numOfStars = 5;
int numOfSpace = 2;


while(numOfStars > 0){
  Console.Write(new string('*', numOfStars));
  Console.Write(new string(' ', numOfSpace));
  Console.WriteLine(new string('*', numOfStars));
  numOfStars--;
  numOfSpace+=2;
}

numOfStars = 2;
numOfSpace = 8;

while(numOfStars < 6){
  Console.Write(new string('*', numOfStars));
  Console.Write(new string(' ', numOfSpace));
  Console.WriteLine(new string('*', numOfStars));
  numOfStars++;
  numOfSpace-=2;
}
```

There are a hundred different ways of doing is pattern, the object lessons here are:

- name things well - as a developer coming by along to "maintain" your code I looked at it and thought "ugh; I'm not even going to bother to understand it, I'll  just delete it and start over"
- make your code describe what it does by the way it is written - my code doesn't really need any comments; the only trick that isn't too obvious is that string has a constructor that takes a char and an int and makes a string that is that char repeated that number of times
- use things that make your life easier wherever possible, like that constructor
- don't get too clever; I thought about exploiting the maths relationship that there are always 12 chars on a line, calculating the number of stars as (12-spaces)/2, printed twice la la, even adding a variable for step so that a single loop could be used, turning around the increment directions after half way.. but then I thought "why add the complexity?". Never confuse the difference between something that is short and something that is clear - just because fewer lines of code are used doesn't make them easier to understand

Answer (score 1):

Here's another sort of hack-ey way to do it:

```
public static void DrawShape(int maxStars)
{
    int lineLength = maxStars * 2 + 2;

    for (int row = 0; row < lineLength - 1; row++)
    {
        int starCount = maxStars - row;
        if (starCount == 0 || starCount == -1) continue;  // This is the hackey line
        if (starCount < 0) starCount *= -1;

        int spaceCount = lineLength - starCount * 2;

        string stars = new string('*', starCount);
        string spaces = new string(' ', spaceCount);

        Console.WriteLine(stars + spaces + stars);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A brute force approach. A simple method that takes two parameters, one for the number of spaces on a line, the second parameter for the number of “*” characters to write…

```
 private static void WriteCharacters(int numSpaces, int numChars) {
  Console.Write(new string('*', numChars));
  Console.Write(new string(' ', numSpaces));
  Console.Write(new string('*', numChars));
  Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Then, write all nine lines…

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
  WriteCharacters(2, 5);
  WriteCharacters(4, 4);
  WriteCharacters(6, 3);
  WriteCharacters(8, 2);
  WriteCharacters(10, 1);
  WriteCharacters(8, 2);
  WriteCharacters(6, 3);
  WriteCharacters(4, 4);
  WriteCharacters(2, 5);
  Console.ReadKey();
}
```